# Only show content before more tag

Tags: the-content, read-more

I am using the Siren Template. In homepage.php this code is used to display the portfolio content

```
print_excerpt(200);
```

But I to need show the content only before `<!--more-->`

I have used this:

```
the_content( $more_link_text, FALSE);
```

but it is not working. It shows all the content

Comment: This is a premium theme that we don't have access to

Comment: i use free version http://topwpthemes.com/siren/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the WordPress function [`get_extended`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_extended) to fetch the different parts of a string (the part before and the part after the `<!--more-->` tag). `get_extended` returns an array with three keys, of which the keys `main` and `extended` are important: `$arr['main']` contains the part before the more tag, and `$arr['extended']` the part after the more tag.

This would yield something like:

```
// Fetch post content
$content = get_post_field( 'post_content', get_the_ID() );

// Get content parts
$content_parts = get_extended( $content );

// Output part before <!--more--> tag
echo $content_parts['main'];
```

Comment: Small improvement to be consistent with `the_content()` function: `echo apply_filters('the_content', $content_parts['main']);`

Comment: I had issues block filters not running properly against the `$content_parts['extended']`, even when using `apply_filters('the_content', $content_parts['extended'])`. The solution was to first run `$filtered_content = apply_filters('the_content', $content)` and run `$content_parts = get_extended( $filtered_content )` after.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunally it seems like all functions in WordPress that are supposed to render the excerpt (`get_extended`, `get_extended`) don't apply HTML tags nor convert carriage returns in paragraphs as aspected.

If you need to render the excerpt with formatting, I suggest that you use this code:

```
global $more;
$more_backup = $more;
$more = 0;
the_content('');
$more = $more_backup;
```

With this work-around you are telling to the_content() function that it is inside a loop, getting the content before the more tag.