# Put teaser content, more-link and full content in different divs if existing... Possible?

Tags: content, the-content, read-more

im working on a flip-card template and have a problem.

```
<div class="card" id="card-<?php the_ID(); ?>">  
    <div class="front"> 
    <div class="card-headline"><?php the_title( '', '' ); ?></div>

        <div class="card-text"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        <div class="card-tags">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-link flip-btn">FLIP<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
    </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="back">
        <div class="card-headline"><?php the_title( '', '' ); ?> (2)</div>

        <div class="card-text-back">Text</div>
        <div class="card-tags"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-link flip-btn">FLIP BACK<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

i would like to place the teaser text before the more link on the front page, place a more link if there is more at the FLIP button and post the content after the more link on the second page. Is that possible? how ca i call the different parts?

i found some help in : [Only show content before more tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149099/only-show-content-before-more-tag)

```
// Fetch post content
$content = get_post_field( 'post_content', get_the_ID() );

// Get content parts
$content_parts = get_extended( $content );

// Output part after <!--more--> tag
echo $content_parts['extended'];
```

but this gives my the content of the second part withoud functioning shortcodes. so it outputs [] for zotero for example

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution which is working.
Splitting the array like above just gives you the plain text so shortcodes wont work.

this works:

```
global $post;
$content = get_extended( $post->post_content ); //get the_content

$excerpt = $content['main']; //get the teaser part before more tag
$main_content = apply_filters('the_content', $content['extended']); //get part after more tag

echo $excerpt; //post teaser part
echo $main_content; //post main part
```

my head is smoking. too much for a beginner

and if you want to have

in your html use this:

```
echo wpautop( $main_content );
```